# Django MakeMessages missing xgettext in Windows

Tags: python, django, windows-7, xgettext

Running Django on Windows 7.

I'm currently trying to translate a couple of Django templates using the instructions found in the django book chapter 19. I've added a translation tag to the template, loaded I18N, and modified django settings. Then I run django-admin.py makemessages -l en to create the po files. All folders are created but then django terminates with the following error:

*Error: errors happened while running xgettext on **init**.py
'xgettext' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

Reading up on the problem, I've discovered that django uses the gnu gettext library for unix based systems. To remedy this I installed cygwin which downloaded and installed the gettext package version 0.18.1.0 which I then added to my PATH. Sadly that did not solve anything. Cygwin did not add any xgettext files whatsoever.

My question is now this. Is there an easy way (or a tutorial) to install xgettext and the other functionality django's internationalization will require **on Windows 7** without having to download a ton of assorted gnu packages. Django has been excellent so far in minimizing unnecessary hardships and these sudden difficulties are not characteristic of django at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

please see http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1157. you do not need cygwin. try these files: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gettext/files/

EDIT:

http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/gettext-tools-0.17.zip

http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/gettext-runtime-0.17-1.zip

the above links are from this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/django-i18n/browse_thread/thread/577afdaef1392958?pli=1

Comment: The gettext for win32 project is out of date. Their latest version is 0.13.xxx and django requires at least 0.15.x

Comment: Downloaded and set it to Path, set all programs to win xp compatiblity mode and to run as admin. Ran makemessages and it worked like a charm. I had almost given up after spending nearly 8 hours on this today. Thanks and /hug!

Comment: On Win7x64 I have to put xgettext.exe and gettext.exe to win xp compatiblity mode.