# Can't find msguniq. Django 1.8, Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: django, windows, windows-7-x64, gettext

I've successfully installed msguniq (can check its version), I've tried to change compatibility to windows xp and run it as administator, but still I'm getting this error:

> CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools
>   0.15 or newer installed.

I'm really confused because I've done everything like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612259/django-makemessages-missing-xgettext-in-windows). I'm really out of ideas how can I fix it (also tried to change gettext.exe and xgettext.exe to windows xp compatibility).

Answer (score 8):

I was having the extact same problem. And it came down to simply restart the cmd window by closing and opening it again.

Of course, you may need if not already done to install Gettext for Windows 0.15 or higher from these sources :

http://mlocati.github.io/gettext-iconv-windows/

To see how I compiled them (if you want to do it yourself) take a look at https://github.com/mlocati/gettext-iconv-windows ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985482/how-to-install-gnu-gettext-on-windows-7))

Make sure also that the path to your gettext is in your system $PATH (python >> import sys >> print sys.path) - if not, you can add in your virtualenv folder Lib\site-packages a .pth file containing the path to your gettext folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check your system path of Gettext.

- Set the `C:\Program Files (x86)\gettext-iconv\bin\`
- Not `C:\Program Files (x86)\gettext-iconv\bin`

Note the `\` at the end.