# Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed. (Django 1.10.5 and OS Windows 10

Tags: python, django

Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed. (Django 1.10.5 and OS Windows 10)

I'm trying to internationalize a Django app by following the wonderful Django documentation. The problem is when I try to run command to create language files:

**python manage.py makemessages --all**

It outputs an error :
Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.

Answer (score 0):

Think it's duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841832/cant-find-msguniq-django-1-8-windows-7-64-bit). Try installing windows version of gettext from [here](http://mlocati.github.io/gettext-iconv-windows/).